# Find the domain of its inverse function

Tags: functions, trigonometry, inverse, inverse-function

Find the domain of the inverse of the function y=(4/pi)*arctan(x).
Given that |x|>1 .

Comment: Is this the inverse function given already?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Not yet, that is the original function

Comment: The inverse function is given by $$y=\tan\left(\frac{\pi x}{4}\right)$$

Comment: Domain of inverse function is range of the function whose inverse it is.

Comment: @Certainlynotadog How to find the range?

Comment: You define it with the function. You have to make sure this function is bijective before you do it and hence set the domain and find its respective range. You can find the "natural" range using differentiation, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain of the inverse funvtion of $$y=(4/\pi)*\arctan(x)$$ is the domain of $$ y=tan(\pi x/4)$$.

with the given condition of $|x|>1$

Thus we have $$|\pi x/4 |<\pi/2$$ and $$|x|>1$$ which implies $$1<|x|<2$$

Comment: But the answer is 1<|x|<2

Comment: @SusanTandiono Thanks for the comment.  I have edited my answer.

Comment: Where does the (pi/2) come from?

Comment: @SusanTandiono   In order to have an inverse we restrict the domain of tangent to$ (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$